# dplyr::lag() problem with many conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to use `dplyr::lag()` with `ifelse` using 3 conditions and rules. If factor `S` then `NA`, if the factor is `D` then `monitor`, but if `D` repeat continuously and just only continuously three-time or more, them "Combat"
I try to do:

```
         test<-NULL
         test$groups <-c("S","D","D","D","D","S","D","D","S")
         test <- as.data.frame(test)
         test%>%mutate(decision = ifelse(groups  == "D", "Monitor",ifelse(groups  == "D" & lag(groups, 2) == "D","Monitor", ifelse(groups  == "D"  & lag(groups, 3) == "D", "Combat",NA))))
  groups decision
1      S     <NA>
2      D  Monitor
3      D  Monitor
4      D  Monitor
5      D  Monitor
6      S     <NA>
7      D  Monitor
8      D  Monitor
9      S     <NA>
```

But is wrong, my correct output is:

```
  groups decision
1      S     <NA>
2      D  Monitor
3      D  Monitor
4      D  Combat
5      D  Combat
6      S     <NA>
7      D  Monitor
8      D  Monitor
9      S     <NA>
```

Please, any help with it?

Comment: Thanks, @akrun, but unfortunately lines 7 and 8 are not "Combat" but "Monitor" a cause o `S` in line 6. "D"  just only continuously three-time or more is `Combat` any `S`interruption is `Monitor` condition.

Comment: Is true the original lag of 3 is wrong @akrun, my bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[,id:=rleid(groups)][groups=="D",decision:=fifelse(1:.N>=3, "Combat","Monitor"), by=id][,.(groups,decision)]
```

Output:

```
   groups decision
   <char>   <char>
1:      S     <NA>
2:      D  Monitor
3:      D  Monitor
4:      D   Combat
5:      D   Combat
6:      S     <NA>
7:      D  Monitor
8:      D  Monitor
9:      S     <NA>
```

Or, you can also do like this (but I still incorporate the use of `data.table::rleid`

```
test %>% 
  group_by(id:=data.table::rleid(groups)) %>% 
  mutate(decision = case_when(
    groups=="D" & row_number()>=3 ~ "Combat",
    groups=="D" & row_number()<3 ~"Monitor",
    TRUE~as.character(NA))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(!id)

# A tibble: 9 x 2
  groups decision
  <chr>  <chr>   
1 S      NA      
2 D      Monitor 
3 D      Monitor 
4 D      Combat  
5 D      Combat  
6 S      NA      
7 D      Monitor 
8 D      Monitor 
9 S      NA
```